# Object Array tricky things

Tags: javascript

now I have an object like `let x = {};`
what I wanna do is to be able to result in something like

```
{'1':[obj,obj,obj], '2':[obj,obj]}
```

so what I do is `x[id] = [obj]` cause here I receive an object but I wanna produce an array of objects with concat to result like the example I mentioned.
SO, here is the problem it overrides the array of objects every time how I can concat here ??

Comment: Could you please paste your code block which you are doing the job?

Comment: `x[id] = x[id] || []; x[id].push(obj)` Or `(x[id] ||= []).push(obj)`

Answer (score 1):

Spread the current values and add the new obj

```
x[id] = [...x[id],obj]
```

Comment: This is [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), not destructuring. And, this will throw an error initially when there is no `id` key

Comment: Correct, OP should check that.